# Recording a 5 second video every hour using python

Tags: pi-4

trying to run an experiment, super new to Raspberry pi would love a basic code and an explanations of it if, or just any helpfull link to any resources, also can i make it auto boot(record 5sec every hour) up once i plug the pi into a wall or something?
this what i got so far

```
ts_now = datetime.datetime.now()

stap = datetime.timedelta(minutes = 60)

camera=PiCamera()

while True:
    if datetime.datetime.now() >= ts_now:
        
        camera.start_preview()
        camera.start_recording('/home/pi/Desktop/videoh264')
        sleep(5)
        camera.stop_recording()
        camera.stop_preview()
    
        ts_now = ts_now + stap    
    else time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: what is your question? ... what is the result of running your code?

Answer (score 2):

## Solution Two

The second solutions is to build it out as a daemon so that it automatically runs on system start. This is more complex, but gives you the benefit of a long-running task which makes it easier to modify and improve your script down the line.

### Systemd is your friend

You will need to create a service file in `/etc/systemd/system` configured to start your script.

I would also suggest that you have some tests inside your script which will ensure that the camera module is awake first, and also that the filesystem has not run out of space.

### Sample service script

This is an example of a service script which *may* prove useful to you.

#### Explanation

This script should start when your network has booted up, and then run your script. If your script crashes, then it will try to restart it. It is only a basic proof-of-concept, and most likely would require some work to get it running as you like. Further assistance can be obtained from the excellent post here:

- https://seb.jambor.dev/posts/systemd-by-example-part-1-minimization/

**Again** This *will most likely* require modification to suit your goals

```
[Unit]
Description=My Cool Camera Grabber
# If network is up, boot process is generally completed.
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
# Modify this to point to your scripts folder
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi
# Modify this to point to your script
ExecStart=/home/pi/coolscript.py
TimeoutStopSec=30
Restart=always
RestartSec=60
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

...and your script would look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Let's assume that this file is called coolscript.py, is executable,
# and is in the "/home/pi/" folder
import datetime
import PiCamera
camera=PiCamera()
camera.start_preview()
while True:
    ts_now = datetime.datetime.now()
    # Create a nice string for our filename
    timeString = ts_now.strftime('%d%m%Y_%H:%m')

    # This assumes that camera.start_recording takes the filename as a function
    camera.start_recording(f'/home/pi/Desktop/videoh264.{timeString}')
    sleep(5)
    camera.stop_recording()
    # Sleep for an hour minus 5 seconds
    sleep(3595)
```

#### Caveat

None of this has been tested, so some tweaking & exploration may be necessary

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions you can use to achieve your goals.

## Solution One

The first, and easiest, would be setting  up a Cron task which executes your script every hour (or whenever you wish).

This would mean modifying your script to just get the time, record video and quit. For example...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Let's assume that this file is called coolscript.py, is executable,
# and is in the "/home/pi/" folder
import datetime
import PiCamera

ts_now = datetime.datetime.now()
# Create a nice string for our filename
timeString = ts_now.strftime('%d%m%Y_%H:%m')
camera=PiCamera()

# Unsure if you require the preview, so you may want to take it out
camera.start_preview()
# This assumes that camera.start_recording takes the filename as a function
camera.start_recording(f'/home/pi/Desktop/videoh264.{timeString}')
sleep(5)
camera.stop_recording()
```

... and in your cron, you would have the following line:
`0 * * * * /home/pi/coolscript.py`

Explanation: The above line will (hopefully) execute your "coolscript.py" file every hour on the hour. See here for a cron calculator:

- https://crontab.tech/

In order to edit your crontab, follow the guide here:

- https://raspiserver.com/crontab-on-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Chenmunka They are two possible solutions to achieve the same goal. Both should work as requested and are equally valid. I see no reason to split the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to understand is that the Raspberry Pi does not have a real time clock (RTC).

Your timing code may work - when the Pi is shut down, it stores its idea of clock time, and resumes from that time when the Pi is restarted. Ideally, you need either an internet connection (so the Pi gets the current time from the internet) or a clock add-on. There are lots of results if you search for Pi4 RTC.

If you use any of the auto-start suggestions, you will need to allow time for the internal clock to be initialised.